# In homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If the solution to an ode is an exponential of x multiplied by $\sin x$ , what “guess” do i use for $y_p$ in order to solve the equation?
I have tried using the guess $e^x(A\sin x + B\cos x)$ but i think it comes out wrong

Comment: Can you post the actual ODE?

Answer (score 0):

If you have $e^{px}(\cos{(kx)})$, you usually want something of the form

$y_p=c_1e^{(m+ik)x}$, with m or k possibly changing signs. Complex exponentials should simplify the math.